# Register a shared preference change listener via xml

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, sharedpreferences

My application requires to be notified about changes in its preferences. I'm using this api and all works fine:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences([my component]).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener([my component]);
```

this code is executed at startup registering a BroadcastReceiver for **android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED**.

I'd like to keep the minimum required permissions profile so I was wondering if it was possible to register a shared preferences change listener via xml in the application manifest so that I can remove the BroadcastReceiver and drop the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Thanks in advance,

L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this code is executed at startup registering a BroadcastReceiver for android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED.

That is useless, as your process should be going away shortly after executing this code, thereby removing your listener.

> I was wondering if it was possible to register a shared preferences change listener via xml in the application manifest so that I can remove the BroadcastReceiver and drop the permission

No, sorry.

> a linux-subsystem daemon read and write on this shared preferences file

<strike>A running Java process will not see changes to a preferences file, where those changes are made by another process.</strike>

`SharedPreferences` is a data storage mechanism. It is not an inter-process communications mechanism. To communicate between a native process and a Dalvik process, please use `Binder`, the way the Android system services do.

Comment: A number of good points in your answer, but the comment about one process not seeing changes made by another process isn't true. In Android < 2.3 this does actually work, and in Android > 2.3 it will work if you open the `SharedPreferences` using `Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS`. In 2.3 it is definitely broken :-(

Comment: @DavidWasser:  Sorry, I was going by http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html "Note: currently this class does not support use across multiple processes. This will be added later." I will strike out the erroneous part of my answer (once I remember how to do strikethrough in Markdown...). Thanks!

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us ;-) Try `<strike>` or `<del>`

Comment: I've wrote down only the minimum informations for the question, omitting the unnecessary: the boot complete receiver spawns a service and the listener is kept alive. I cannot change the underlying process structure because is not my mandate, but i can read the native process changes to preferences without any problem. May be CommonsWare did not read what I wrote: the application currently is running in field and it works pretty well. The only information that I needed is that i cannot register a listener on the manifest. So I accept the answer.